# Image getting out paragraph block

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm making my own website but when I have posts where I put images, the images go out the paragraph blocks. So I need to resize the height to the height of the paragraph block. I have already tried several things but I can't get it to work.

Here is a screenshot of it:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwycm.png)

Here is my CSS:

```
.content-area p img
{
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
}

.content-area p
{
    font-family: Geo;
    font-size: 140%;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #615e61;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3d93ba;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: make the image height 100% not auto.

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? Can you also tell where exactly do you want the image to be placed?

Comment: can you post jsfiddle link for your question?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)